# For loop causing tkinter to freeze

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter application which does some clicking automation for a game. Essentially I want the user to press the start button afterward which the clicker will start. The function has two for loops in which there are some time.sleep statements. The issue I am having is that I want the user to be able to press the same button to start/stop the function. I have tried threading and it did not work. See code below.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import time
from system_hotkey import SystemHotkey
from tkhtmlview import HTMLLabel
import threading

quenched_coords = [1690, 377]
drag_coords = [1071, 708]
confirm_coords = [1816, 905]
quench_time = 12
firstitem_coords = [511, 176]
x_increment = 108
y_increment = 108
inventory = [514, 629]




hk = SystemHotkey()
tracking_var = False

def loop(toggle=False):
    global tracking_var
    if toggle:
        if tracking_var:
            tracking_var = False
        else:
            tracking_var = True


    if tracking_var:
        for i in range(5):

            if tracking_var:
    
                for j in range(9):

                    if tracking_var:
                
                    
                        pyautogui.moveTo(firstitem_coords)
                        pyautogui.dragTo(quenched_coords, button='left', duration=1)
                        time.sleep(0.2)
                        pyautogui.moveTo(confirm_coords)
                        time.sleep(0.7)
                        pyautogui.click()
                        time.sleep(quench_time)
                        pyautogui.moveTo(quenched_coords)
                        pyautogui.dragTo(drag_coords, button='left', duration=1) 
                        time.sleep(0.2)
                        firstitem_coords[0]+=x_increment
                    else:
                        print("exiting")
                        break
                        
                firstitem_coords[0] = 511
                firstitem_coords[1]+=y_increment

                if i==1:
                    pyautogui.moveTo(1451, 144)
                    pyautogui.click()
                    pyautogui.scroll(-1000)
                    firstitem_coords[1]=176
            else:
                print("exiting")
                break
        window.after(0, loop)

def run():
    print("threading")
    threading.Thread(target=loop(True)).start()


    
    
window = Tk()



title_text = StringVar()

clicked2 = StringVar()
clicked2.set("ALT + Q")


temp2 = hotkeystring(clicked2)

b2 = Button(window, text = "Start/Stop\n({0})".format(clicked2.get()), command=run, font="Raleway", bg="gray16", fg="white", height=2, width=15)
b2.grid(row=0,column=0)

hk.register(hotkeystring(clicked2), callback=lambda event: b2.invoke())
  
window.mainloop()
```

Essentially I want the button to be able to start/stop the script no matter where it is currently in the loop. How do I go about this? Currently this code just freezes tkinter as soon as the user presses start. Pressing this button again does not do anything.

Comment: Sleep makes your application pause? That's what it's supposed to do!

Comment: *I have tried threading and it did not work* -- then you didn't do it right.  Tkinter, like all GUI frameworks, is event driven.  As long as you have a handler running, the Tkinter main loop cannot run, and no events (like mouse motion and clicks) can be processed.  You either need to do the processing in a thread, or figure out how to do it a piece at a time and use `root.after` to get a callback.

Comment: Or, find a way to 'do something after a set period of time' without using 'sleep' .

Answer (score 1):

you have a small typo

```py
threading.Thread(target=loop(True)).start()
```

`loop(True)` is evaluated before the thread is created, so `loop(True)` is called by the main process, which is not what you want.

you wanted to do this :

```py
threading.Thread(target=loop,args=(True,)).start()
```

this sets target to be the function loop then calls it with argument (True)

Comment: This worked, thank you.